# What's best between a script with a lot of functions and a script with one big function that can do all the work?

Tags: javascript, function

It's been a month now that i really got into javascript. I made a raphael.js big script that contains a few functions that draw a diagrams. Basically these diagrams appearance are based on the same parameters, but the disposition of the elements is different for each function.
I'm a big noob, so i don't want to start with bad practices. That's why i'm asking.
For now my script looks like this :

```
var typeOfDrawing;
draw(){
  if(typeOfDrawing == 1){
  /* Ajax query to get the parameters I need */
  paper.clear();
  /* drawing stuff*/
  setTimeout(draw,5000);
  }
}

 draw2(){
  if(typeOfDrawing == 2){
  /* Ajax query to get the parameters I need */
  paper.clear();
  /* drawing stuff*/
  setTimeout(draw2,5000);
  }
}

 draw3(){
  if(typeOfDrawing == 3){
  /* Ajax query to get the parameters I need */
  paper.clear();
  /* drawing stuff*/
  setTimeout(draw3,5000);
  }
}

 draw4(){
  if(typeOfDrawing == 4){
  /* Ajax query to get the parameters I need */
  paper.clear();
  /* drawing stuff*/
  setTimeout(draw4,5000);
  }
}

/* Here I get a bootstrap's datepicker value when the user chooses a date */
$('#dp1').datepicker()
          .on('changeDate', function(ev){
              $("#paper1").show();
              date =""+ $("#dp1").datepicker("getDate"); 
              day = date.substring(0,3);
              /* This returns the first 3 letters of the selected day so i can  
                 chose which drawing i have to launch */
              switch(day){
                    case "Mon":
                        typeOfDrawing=2;
                        draw3();
                        break;
                    case "Tue":
                    case "Wed":
                    case "Thu":
                    case "Fri":
                        typeOfDrawing=0;
                        draw();
                        break;
                    case "Sat":
                        typeOfDrawing=3;
                        draw4();
                        break;
                    case "Sun":
                        typeOfDrawing=4;
                        draw5();

              }
          });
```

Basically that's the part of my script i believe is relevant for you to understand what I'm about to ask :

What's best between the code I wrote, and some big function that would do all the drawing according with the day in parameter. Like this :

```
drawTotal(day){
  switch(day){
    case "Mon" :
         /* drawing instructions corresponding to draw3() */
    case "Tue" :
    case "Wed" :
    case "Thu" :
    case "Fri" :
         /* drawing instructions corresponding to draw() */
    case "Sat" :
         /* drawing instructions corresponding to draw4() */
    case "Sun" :
         /* drawing instructions corresponding to draw5() */

  setTimeout(drawTotal,5000);
  }
}
```

I tried to simplify it enough, if it's not clear don't hesitate to ask for details^^

Comment: There's no right or wrong, and "best" or "worse" is very opinion based, not to mention you don't specify the constraints. It's perhaps best if you are trying to change it later, or best in performance aspects, but still, it's very opinion based.

Comment: Definitely a good idea to get feedback on your code. However, there's a seperate [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) site for that.

Comment: The question is sort of off-topic, but it's generally a good design practice to make each function do one thing and only one thing. It's also good to move logic from code into data as much as you can; this looks like it might be a candidate for that.

Comment: @TomZych I love the generic approach of putting logic in to data, +1 therefor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JS is quite procedural. Putting the function bodies in between the cases of the switch makes it even more procedural.

As the nature of JS is more OO-oriented, I recommend to put the switch from the AJAX in to an object together with the particular drawing functions.

Construct a class with a more generic approach and less redundancy and with out any global variable like `typeOfDrawing`.

The benefit of this is not in performance but in

- better readability of the code
- better maintenance of the code in future
- less dependency between parts of your application
- better encapsulation of particular logic

just my 2 cents. And of course this should better go [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).